# Using dplyr distinct to ignore geometries of sf object in R

Tags: r, dplyr, spatial, r-sf

I have a dataset with multiple polygons in different locations that share the same attributes. I only want one polygon in my dateset for each set of unique attributes (so in my example below, that would be `Area` and `Zone`) - I don't care about where they are so I want to ignore the geometry attribute.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

    Areas <- st_as_sf(tibble(
      Area =c("Zone1", "Zone1","Zone2","Zone1"),
      Zone =c("Area27","Area27","Area42","Area27"),
      lng = c(20.1, 20.2, 20.1, 20.1),
      lat = c(-1.1, -1.2, -1.1, -1.1)),
    coords = c("lng", "lat")) %>% st_buffer(.,100)
```

I am using dplyr distinct to remove duplicate records, but I am finding the geometry column is being used to determine distinct records, even though I believe this should be ignoring the geometry column:

```
Areas %>% distinct(across(-geometry),.keep_all=TRUE)
```

However, it is returns two results for Zone1 and Area27 when the geometry is different. Is this expected behaviour or am I do something wrong?

My required output would only have two rows in it, one for Zone1 & Area27 and another for Zone2 & Area42 with the geometry for those rows retained i.e. something similar to what happens you run the same code on a normal tibble:

```
Table <- tibble(
  Area =c("Zone1", "Zone1","Zone2","Zone1"),
  Zone =c("Area27","Area27","Area42","Area27"),
  lng = c(20.1, 20.2, 20.1, 20.1),
  lat = c(-1.1, -1.2, -1.1, -1.1))

Table %>% distinct(across(c(-lng,-lat)),.keep_all=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found an alternative method:

```
Areas %>% group_by(Area,Zone) %>% 
          mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
          filter(id == 1) %>% 
          select(-id)
```

If you are dealing with a dataset with a lot of polygons this is likely to be faster than @Waldi's answer (at least it was for me).

Answer (score 0):

You could summarize :

```
Areas  %>% group_by(Area,Zone) %>% summarize()

# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   Area [2]
  Area  Zone                                                                          geometry
  <chr> <chr>                                                                        <POLYGON>
1 Zone1 Area27 ((120.2 -1.2, 120.063 -6.433596, 119.6522 -11.65285, 118.9688 -16.84345, 118.0~
2 Zone2 Area42 ((120.1 -1.1, 119.963 -6.333596, 119.5522 -11.55285, 118.8688 -16.74345, 117.9~
```

Comment: That's one option. However (and I didn't make it clear in the original question), I need to keep the geometry as I have other spatial operations to perform on the data after this point.

Comment: Does the other option in my edit fulfill your needs? Difficult to be distinct with 2 different geometries, you somehow need to lose the geometry info at least in this pipe, or make a group_by and keep the first geometry value.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I was under the impression that 'distinct(across(-geometry)' would ignore the geometry field when looking for distinct features. It doesn't appear to be doing that and the only solution appears to be removing the geometry (which is not desired). This doesn't seem right to me as the same code works on a normal tibble (see the other example I have added to my question).

Comment: OK, I think I got it, see my edit : keeps geometry, is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes it would, so thanks for that. It does seem weird that distinct doesn't do the job, but there you go!

Comment: geometry is a sf class which doesn't seem to fully behave like a standard dataframe column...